JavaScript parsing year 1 as 2000
I'm experiencing this issue in both Node.js v16.20.2 and in a browser console:
> new Date(Date.parse('0001-01-01'))
0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

OK, I expected this. Now consider this:
> new Date(Date.parse('0001-01-01 00:00:00'))
2000-12-31T23:00:00.000Z

Year 2000?
This works just fine:
> new Date(Date.parse('0001-01-01T00:00:00Z'))
0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

I know how to fix it and I also know how dates should be parsed, but I'm looking for an explanation of why this behavior happens.

Have you checked out the different implementation details that are not very cross-browser compatible? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#non-standard_date_strings - It seems Date.parse("0") results in it starting in 2000 when in chromium, which is what nodejs also uses. That seems similar to your string starting with 0.

You should ensure that your date strings are properly formatted without any trailing spaces. If you want to work with UTC time explicitly, you can append "T00:00:00Z" to your date string

Step even one character outside of the one documented format, and all bets are off.

Does this answer your question? Parsing a string to a date in JavaScript

@jonrsharpe guess i got my answer here.. undefined behavior.

@somethinghere thanks for the link! I had not found that yet

As pointed out in the comments, the format with the space is non-standard so all bets are off.
It looks like on Node.js/Chrome it's being parsed as MM-DD-YY HH:MM:SS:
new Date(Date.parse('0001-02-03 04:05:06'))
// 2003-01-02T04:05:06.000Z

(The results depend on the local timezone.)

Worth adding that two digit years are typically parsed as 1900 + the year. cf per ECMA-262, new Date(0, 0, 1) creates a date for 1 Jan 1900, not 1 Jan 0000.

@RobG: The non-standard string formats are a mess -- "Jan 1, 50" is parsed as 1950 but "Jan 1, 49" is parsed as 2049.
